# Converting multiple JSON object to one list Mule dataweave

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am having input as below

```js
{
  "ResidentialAddress": {
"type": "RES",
"Building": "String"
  },
  "Name": "Satheesh",
  "Status": "Active",
  "OfficeAddress": {
"type": "OFC",
"Building": "String"
  },
  "TempAddress": {
"type": "TEMP",
"Building": "String"
  }
}
```

I am looking to convert it as below

```js
{Address:[
{
 "type": "RES",
 "Building": "String"
 },
 {
  "type": "OFC",
  "Building": "String"
  },{
   "type": "TEMP",
   "Building": "String"
   }


]}
```

When i tried with address:payload.ResidentialAddress ++ payload.TempAddress it give me combined fields not a list can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In dataweave use the **flatten** operation. after dataweave set payload .

```
     %dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 ---
(flatten payload) filter ($.type != null)
```

final xml file would be

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[ %dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 ---
 (flatten payload) filter ($.type != null)]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-payload value="{&quot;Address&quot;: #[payload]}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: hey mate I have edited my questioon, the problem is there are few other fields in between if I use flatten payload those fields are also included which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for filtering any fields that have string/integer/boolean values:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---

{
 Address: (flatten payload) filter ($ is :object)
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have 300 fields like this,for example I just gave 2

Comment: @SatheeshKumar I have updated my answer to make the filtering more generic. Can you give this a try?

Answer (score 0):

Against your test data:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{ Address:payload filter $ is :object map $}
```

gives:

```
 {
  "Address": [
    {
      "type": "RES",
      "Building": "String"
    },
    {
      "type": "OFC",
      "Building": "String"
    },
    {
      "type": "TEMP",
      "Building": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

but you may need to tweak the filter to work with your real data...